# Pass JSON string in REST URL

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

Using REST for the first time and trying to send JSON string as path variable in REST request URL, what I am doing to send a request from client:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
    json.put("Test", "123");
    json.put("tracks", "1234");
    jj = json.toString();
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e1.printStackTrace();
}

   String url =  "http://localhost:8090/webApp/restresource/"+jj+".do";
   st = (String) restTemplate.postForObject(url,jj, String.class, jj);
```

Rest server:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/restresource/{code}", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes= "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String useJson(@PathVariable String jj) {

    String result;

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        result = jObject.getJSONObject(jj).toString();

    } catch (JSONException jse) {
        jse.printStackTrace();
    }

return result;

}
```

Exception I get is `not enough variable values to expand "Test"`

EDIT: my request url looks like this:

`http://localhost:8090/app/restResource/%7B%22%22:%22123%22,%22tracks%22:%221234%22%7D.do`

Even saw the HttpClientErrorException!  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using JSON as GET parameter transport mechanism, anyway? Also, note that you add ".do" suffix when sending but your RequestMapping pattern doesn't include it so the whole string will be parsed as JSON, leading to an exception. Plus, looks like you're not sharing your real code as you don't even use `jj` variable in `useJson`.

Comment: while testing, I used without `.do` which failed when I added that at the end of url It went through to show the result. using `jj`, just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is :

```
HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(json); // Create HTTP Entity to post to rest endpoint
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, Object.class);
```

In your server side, you do not need to access this as PathVariable instead you can use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/restresource", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes= "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String useJson(@RequestBody JSonObject object) {
```

Hence spring framework automatically convert the json string into the specified object type.
You can adjust your URL accordingly and try again.

Comment: Used to get the message converter exception, but after adding this in config file it went away.

Comment: I have all the jars annotations, data-bind and core but still it says, objectMapper not found. isn't it included in core?

Comment: do you have this dependency in the classpath                   <dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.5</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: is this supported with 2.2.1 jackson core? and when I added 1.9.6 mapper-acl, it says org.codehaus.jackson.version is missing!

Comment: this what I am getting now `Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.json.JSONObject]` 
Config file has this: `<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" >
          <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />    
      </bean> 
        </array>
     </property>
    </bean>   `

Comment: <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to use below

```
 <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>     
             <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>



<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```