# [] or () in REST Urls

Tags: api, rest, routes

Has anyone used either [] or () in your REST API urls?

hypothetical examples:

```
/cars?[colors]:red,[engineType]:13
/cars?(colors):red,(engineType):13
```

- says give me all cars with color red and a certain engine type.  Colors is a sub property of the car resource.

Has anyone seen any issues using these to be aware of or is it pretty common to use?

Here's another example.  Give me all the cities but only the cities where its people drink coffee

```
/cities?filter=(people[drinks[type]:6])
```

or I could even allow more sets as to perform ANDs like this

```
/cities?filter=(people[drinks[type]:6]),(another layer of filtering)&paging=(offset:10, limit:2)
```

essentially in the second, the comma itself is an implicit AND for the query because () denotes a filtering criteria so we have one filtering criteria, comma, second filtering criteria so this could easily be wired up to SQL via () and () if you think about it when parsing the url values out of the request and passing it down to a query in the backend.

this is an idea I have.

() - denotes one filter level, adding multiple () are multiple filters 
[] - denotes a sub property of a resource

so the above allows the caller to say give me a list of cities but only those whos people like to drink coffee (type 6).

Comment: Why not JSON (http://www.json.org/)?

Comment: I'm talking about the url you send to the REST API.  What do you mean

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19362281/4004512 for an example of this.

Comment: I've seen that, POST goes against REST convention for getting data.  Would prefer not to go that route

Comment: what do you mean why not json, put that where? in the GET?  I do not wanna POST and send json for a GET if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: I'm looking for a scalable way to manage allowing filtering on hierarchies here..

Comment: has anyone even been able to match like that when you create your routes in koa-router?  like having the /someResource/someParam:value...

Comment: You can URL encode a json string and use it as the value of a query string argument. example: `/cars?filter=%7B%22color%22%3A%22red%22%2C%22doors%22%3Atrue%7D` which would be `{"color":"red","doors":true}`. Either way you are over thinking it. Simple query string key value pairs would suffice. `/city?fav_drink=coffee&car_types=trucks`. You do the `AND` in your server side logic. `/city?fav_drink=coffee&car_types=trucks&people=!hipsters` there is some negation for you.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really an official specification of REST, but this is very unusual. The normal way to do this is to urlencode your parameters in key=value form. Almost all libraries are going to help you do that. You'd have to hand-parse this custom format you've invented (and you need to figure out any escaping issues; what if `,` or `[` can be part of the string? It's unclear what the brackets are getting you in any case.

A more usual way to approach this would be:

```
/cars?color=red&engineType=13
```

Comment: right but think more complex.  That's fine for simple filtering.  Think about one level deeper in the filter.  What If I wanted cars with color red and with tint 10 and tint is a sub resource of color.  How in the url would you start specifying a sub resource of a resource and so on.  By using () or [] you can start to allow very specific filtering further down in the chain on that resource's properties and properties of those properties.

Comment: check out my update for a more complex example and idea I have about allowing a consistent way to do more complex querying and how I"m specifying that in my url.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 frequent patterns I met so far:

- `/cars/?colors=red&engineType=13`
- `/cars/colors:red/engineType:13/`

Using [] or () in URIs is not common. I don't think you'll have any issues by using them if that's what you desire. Just don't use {} if you want to use URI templates too.

Comment: I've seen other APIs like Stormpath's which is a real good API use () and stuff like that.

Comment: a lot of apis are also using + as to allow querying syntax also but I'm not going that route

Comment: @MSSucks That's possible. I did not spend too much time to examine URI structures in different REST APIs... As long as your solution meets with the URI standard there is no problem. If it doesn't you'll know from error messages.

Comment: how about when you need to go deeper though like colors.engine.type in a hierarchy?  like /cars/colors.tone:14  see..there's colors and it has a tone property so I'm going lke 3 levels down in properties.

Comment: @WeDoTDD I think the main problem here, that you need a query language and we don't have a standard query language for URI-s. So it does not really matter what kind of URI template you use as long as the server understands it.